# GDAL cubic oversampling problem

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem, resampling, hillshade

I am trying to oversample a part of a big GeoTIFF DEM to display it as a hillshade. I'm doing the process in 3 steps:

- extract a part of my GeoTIFF
- oversample that part
- generate the hillshade with QGIS

Here's the command I use to extract a part:

```
gdal_translate \
    -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 \
    -projwin 3.4999998866667914 43.12434922166657 5.968749886666799 40.78056666958323 \
    dem.tif \
    a.tif
```

When openning a.tif in QGIS and generating a hillshade (using bicubic oversampling), it works as expected:

[image]

Then I oversample a.tif with this command:

```
gdal_translate \
    -r cubic \
    -tr 0.000171662 0.000171662 \
    a.tif \
    b.tif
```

When openning b.tif in QGIS to generate the hillshade and view it at its native resolution, I expect to get the same result as with a.tif, but here's what I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? It nearly looks like a nearest resampling is being used (in QGIS I'm using the exact same parameters to generate the hillshades. I'm also getting the same result with a software I am developping).

I also tried in a single step (using -projwin and -tr at the same time), and with gdalwarp, result is always the same.

EDIT: adding some more tests:

If I do this:

```
gdalwarp \
    -r cubic \
    -te 3.4999998866667914 40.78056666958323 5.968749886666799 43.12434922166657 \
    ../../../emodnet/raw-4326.tif \
    a.tif

gdaldem \
    hillshade \
    -z 1 \
    -s 111120 \
    a.tif \
    a-hillshade.tif

gdalwarp \
    -r cubic \
    -te 3.4999998866667914 40.78056666958323 5.968749886666799 43.12434922166657 \
    -tr 0.000171662 0.000171661 \
    a.tif \
    b.tif

gdaldem \
    hillshade \
    -z 1 \
    -s 111120 \
    b.tif \
    b-hillshade.tif

gdalwarp \
    -r cubic \
    -te 3.4999998866667914 40.78056666958323 5.968749886666799 43.12434922166657 \
    -tr 0.000171662 0.000171661 \
    a-hillshade.tif \
    b-hillshade-2.tif
```

Then:

- a-*.tif have the original resolution, and are displayed correctly in QGIS or Gimp, like in the 1st picture
- b-*.tif have the upscaled resolution
- b.tif & b-hillshade.tif are not displayed correctly, like in the 2nd picture
- b-hillshade-2.tif and the upscaled resolution and is displayed correctly, like in the 1st picture (but I do not need a hillshade tif, I need an upscaled dem)

Comment: Perhaps QGIS is first downsampling b.tif and it may select to use nearest resampling for that. I would make some tests by creating overviews into b.tif with gdaladdo with different   resampling algorithms that the utility supports. Comparing the methods is easier if you create external overviews (-ro). Then you can just delete the .ovr file between the tests.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think so: using gdaldem hillshade and viewing the result with gimp (or QGIS) shows the exact same result.

Comment: What parameters you are using with gdaldem? Do you create the hillside for the full oversampled resolution or for the back-downsampled resolution? Did you test with gdaladdo, it does not take long.

Comment: I used: gdaldem hillshade -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -z 1 -s 111120 b.tif hillshade.tif (so on the resized tif. The original is huge). I'm not sure how gdaladdo could help since I'm viewing the upsampled raster at it native resolution.

Comment: I understood `When openning b.tif in QGIS to generate the hillshade and view it at its native resolution, I expect to get the same result as with a.tif, but here's what I get` that the native resolution is the same in both cases, the native resolution of the original a.tif. So native-b = upsampled-a. And when you compare, are the resolutions/scales the same?

Comment: dem.tif and a.tif have a resolution of 0.001041666666667. b.tif has a resolution of 0.000171662. When generating the hillshade with gdaldem at native resolution and upscaling that, I get the expected result (1st picture). But I need the tiff, not the hillshade (I'm writing a program that will generate the hillshade).

Comment: I may have a try if you can share test data and exact commands. GDAL may not be optimized for upsampling.

Comment: There is lot of discussion about resampling in http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-downsampling-geotiff-with-a-low-pass-filter-td5385890.html but it deals more with downsampling.

Comment: Here's the raw file (= dem.tif): https://dev.www.ewalk.app/tmp/raw.tif (865MB). Tell me if that's too big, I can share an extract. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Comment: Looks like using -r cubicspline when upscaling fixes the problem (it works on a small extract, I now need to try on the whole file).